# Increase precision of ConvexHullMesh

Tags: computational-geometry, arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I want to generate a set of equations for all planes in the convex hull as specified in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226657/73695) question. The problem is that the generated set of equations don't correctly cover all the points. I run a Z3 script to check if all points are included and it can find counter examples on the edge of some plane of the convex hull. As specified [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85709/73695), one solution is to scale the numbers. However, I'm not a computational-geometry person. I have no idea how that would affect the equations that are generated from the convex hull? Can someone please shed some light on if I can use this approach and how? Another option is to use `Rationalize` and then set proper `WorkingPrecision`. But `ConvexHullMesh` does not have that option. Can anyone please tell me how I can generate the convex hull's plane equations with increased precision?

Comment: How about `Rationalize[pts,10^-30]`?

Comment: @user64494 would just converting the number to rationals make the convex hull use more precision? In my understanding, you also had to specify the precision for operations of the algorithm you want by passing ```WorkingPrecision``` option.